# Why Shell_NotifyIcon not showing balloon notification?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have written a sample application to see how balloon notifications can be added to a Win32 application. Can someone please point out why `Shell_NotifyIcon()` is not showing balloon notifications?
`GetLastError` returns `2147500037` for `Shell_NotifyIcon()`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "shellapi.h"

int main()
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATAA_V3_SIZE);
    nid.uTimeout = 500;
    nid.uID = 1;
    nid.uFlags = NIF_TIP | NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_INFO | 0x00000080;
    nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER + 200;
    nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
    lstrcpy(nid.szTip, L"Test Tip");
    lstrcpyW(nid.szInfoTitle, L"Test Title");
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid); //GetLastError returns - 2147500037

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `Shell_NotifyIcon()` is not documented to use `GetLastError()` for error reporting, so you can't rely on `GetLastError()` returning anything meaningful in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use `NOTIFYICONDATA_V3_SIZE` instead of `NOTIFYICONDATAA_V3_SIZE`, as you clearly use Unicode (seen from `lstrcpyW` and `L"..."`), and you use default `NOTIFYICONDATA`

Should just use `nid.cbSize = NOTIFYICONDATA_V3_SIZE;` or `nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA)`, you don't want to have size of integer constant.

Should also check `Shell_NotifyIcon` result before calling to `GetLastErrror`, if it is not `FALSE`, `GetLastError` is not relevant.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Updated code: `nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA_V3_SIZE);`

Comment: Just noticed that you have *sizeof* for integer constant that is already size, you don't need `sizeof`

Comment: It should be NOTIFYICONDATA**W** for Unicode, and Shell_NotifyIcon**W**.

Comment: Updated code, still not working - https://pastebin.pl/view/66ec03aa

Comment: You are also missing HWND to accept your message, and don't  zero fields you don't initialize `szInfo`, `dwState`, `dwStateMask`. (It might work without `HWND` if you at least set it to zero)